# Change Qt install path after building?

Tags: qt, build, path, installation, qmake

how can I change Qt install path after I building it ?

Example : qmake.exe search binaries to original install path, how can I change/redefine it ?

Thanks.

Edit : I finally found this patch to apply to Qt :

- http://ftp-developpez.com/qt/binaires/win32/patcher/QtPatcher.7z
- http://ftp-developpez.com/qt/binaires/win32/patcher/QtPatche_src.7z

Comment: Related: [How to install Qt on Windows after building?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4699311/95735)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I was looking into this and found a way that works (in qt 4.7.2) by customizing qt with a qt.conf file.

In my case, I added a qt4-4.7.2/bin/qt.conf (I think it must be in the same place as the qmake executable)

With the following contents:

```
[Paths]
Prefix = c:/my_path/to/qt4-4.7.2
```

and the qmake -query started returning the proper paths!

See: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qt-conf.html for more details

Comment: Also fixes things for me on Win8 with Qt 4.8.1

Comment: Not sure if this works for older versions, but in Qt 5.5.0 you can do `Prefix=..`, which allows moving the Qt installation pretty much anywhere. Additionally, when translating e.g. QtCommercialCharts, I had to set the `QMAKEFEATURES` environment variable to `%QTDIR%\mkspecs\features"` so qt_build_config is found.

Comment: I'm using 5.5 and `Prefix=./../` make it work for any path.

Comment: Works on Windows 10 with Qt 4.8.6.

Answer (score 4):

You can change path to binaries and many other hardcoded paths in qmake using `qmake -set` command.
See [Configuring qmake's Environment](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmake-environment-reference.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer it for windows, not so sure about others. Remove the path variables if any present in the environmental variable `PATH`.

In Qt-Creator goto,

> Tools->Options->Qt4->Qt Versions

In the right hand side area, you will find **Auto- Detected** and **Manual**. Under **Manual** add a new entry by clicking the **+** symbol in the far right. Specify the QMake location by clicking **Browse** . Change the **Default Qt Version** to your newly specified Version. Of course, you have to re -build the application. Hope that it helps.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix/Linux:

You can also use LD_LIBRARY_PATH+PATH for workarounds. But still, some defaults are hardcoded in the code, yes. A rebuild is a must.

Answer (score 0):

On unix you can make a symbolic link, otherwise you probably need to rebuild it

Comment: FWIW, since Vista, this is possible since in Windows too.

Comment: But they don't have all the properties of links on unix, can you even link directories?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with Qt 5.15.2:

```
cd ~/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/share/qtcreator/QtProject
grep -inr '<olduser>' | cut -d: -f1 | xargs sed -i 's/<olduser>/<newuser>/g'
```

Replace `<olduser>` and `<newuser>` obviously.