# Is it possible to edit the hardcoded path in a Windows (custom built) installation of Qt 5?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

We are building Qt 5.10 internally, and installing it to a given `prefix` on the build environments.

We would like to be able to relocate the installation (notably, but not only for, distribution). We are aware of `qt.conf`, [as pointed out by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7968705/1027706).

Yet, is there a maintained way to directly edit the values of those hardcoded paths in the installed files?

**EDIT:**
More rationale behind why we thing `qt.conf` is inferior to directly patching the binaries.

- On development machines, it means that instead of simply patching the installed binaries **once**, we have to provide a configuration file in each folder containing an application depending on Qt.
- Even worse than that, we discovered through failures (and the help of [this post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/52666/error-resource_bundle-cc-639-failed-to-load-qtwebengine_resources-pak)) that `qtwebengineprocess.exe`, in qtprefix/bin, expects its **own** `qt.conf` file, otherwise it will use the paths hardcoded in the libraries. This means that we have to touch the the library folder anyway, in otder to edit the configuration file to make it match the folder location on each development machine.

Comment: Have a look at the code of `windeployqt` - as far as I know it does exactly that (modify hard coded paths in the Qt dlls)

Comment: @Felix Thank you for the suggestion, but we would like to avoid having to maintain such tool ourselves. It honestly feels a bit of a shame that Qt does not provide a command line tool doing that in their distribution.